# Code based Spring configuration returns Hello World instead of expected jsp page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

After switching from XML to code based Spring configuration the "Hello World!" page is returned after successful log in. Why Spring cannot map controller's methods?

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "app.controller")
public class AppConfig {}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("a")
                        .password("a")
                        .roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
//                    .antMatchers("/signup","/about").permitAll() // #4
                    .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN") // #6
                    .anyRequest().authenticated() // 7
                    .and()
                .formLogin()  // #8
//                .loginUrl("/login") // #9
                .permitAll(); // #5
    }
}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer**

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**WebAppInitializer**

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(SecurityConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

**AppController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String getRequestPage(Model model){
    return "request";
    }
```

I understand that WebAppInitializer links `AppConfig`, `WebMvcConfig` and `SecurityConfig` . `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` seems like lonely class. `AppConfig` suppose to load my `AppController` automatically because of  `@ComponentScan`. Correct? Why is it not working?

**UPDATE**
I have `index.jsp` in `WEB-INF` with `Hello World!`.
**UPDATE2**
request.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<html>
<head>.....</head>....</html>
```

**UPDATE3**
One remark: `auth` is highlighted by IDE saying that `Could not autowire. No beans of AuthenticationManagerBuilder type found`. [Official Spring example](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/) does not include `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` bean explicit definition. Why?

**SOLVED**

I don't know why `index.jsp` overrides the controller mapping. But removing `index.jsp` from WEB-INF/ solved the problem. Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: Can you please paste your "request.jsp" file. Is request.jsp what you are trying to load?

Comment: YOu protected all URLs. `/**` is proteced to be only accesible by administrators.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I know. AFTER I pass valid credentials it redirects me to `index.jsp` completely ignoring my controller.

Comment: @Akshay, Indeed I'm trying to get `request.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your AppConfig. In your WebAppInitializer, you're adding the AppConfig class to "root context". This means, your controller will get scanned and added to the "root context" but the rest of your MVC configuration (WebMvcConfig) will get loaded in web application context (via DispatcherServlet).

In fact, you don't need the App config at all. You can add the @ComponentScan annotation in your WebMvcConfig class like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "app.controller")
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 .... 
}
```

This should let your controller be scanned and added to the web application Context.

Comment: Removed `AppConfig`and added `@ComponentScan` as suggented but problem persists